# VBA: Create a connection to a OLEDB with user ID and Password

Tags: vba, excel, macros, oledb, oledbconnection

I have created some macros to do some SQL queries into the data-base. My problem comes when I try to create a macro to define the connection. Macro recorder doesn't give any answer and none of the posts I have seen on the internet seem to help me. I need a macro to define the IP of the server and to give the user and password credentials.

Do any of you have any idea or can send a link to a webpage that explain how this can be achieved?

Thank you very much!

Comment: check on [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) which works for ADODB but should work for Excel connections, too.

Comment: Thank you. Which of all these examples do you think should I use to implement it in my VBA macro?

Comment: on the front page search for provider, and next search for the scenario which is closest to your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA macro save SQL query in a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744688/vba-macro-save-sql-query-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your help and scuse me for the duplicate. I couldn't find any related post before.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? This works for me. Just keep in mind you have to switch out the right fields.

```
Public Const pathName As String = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & _
                            "SERVER=serverName;UID=usernameHere;PWD=passwordHere"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This look like what I am looking for... The problem is that the codes that I find don't create the connection properly, and I can't figure out where should I add this line... Could you show me the link from where you got this line so that I can fit it.

Comment: I actually did not get this from a link. What I usually do is put all my connection strings in their own module. Then when I want to open them I simply use

Comment: Can't figure out how to edit the comment so I'll just continue. I simply use "con.Open nameOfModule.pathName" and that works just fine. Our way of keeping all our strings in one location.

Comment: Oh! That sounds interesting.
I only have one connection that I want to use. Please tell me if I am right or not... In order to be able to run this, do I need to have created the connection file before? There is not any way to create this connection file from VBA?
As my experience it seems that if I don't have the connection file created  Conn.Open will show an error (invalid connection...)