# Cannot connect to MS SQL db from machines other than local

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, sql-server-express

I am running an `MSSQLServer 2014 Express` instance on my machine with one database that contains one table. I have an Excel VBA application that connects to this DB and retrieves/updates records. This Excel VBA script only connects to the DB from the same machine on which the database is hosted and not from any other client/computer.

I have checked and eliminated possibility of network issues, in that I can successfully ping and telnet into MyIPAddress:1433 from these client machines.

Following are the combinations of connection string that I have tried, none of which works from another machine than the one which hosts the SQL DB. Help appreciated!

`ConnectionStringSQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.0.0.2,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"`

`ConnectionStringSQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.0.0.2,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Username=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword"`

`ConnectionStringSQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PCName;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"`

`ConnectionStringSQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PCName\MSSQLSERVER;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Username=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword"`

`ConnectionStringSQL = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Username=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword"`

Comment: which is the error message? can you connect usign SSMS?

Comment: Have a look at these solutions I provided some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289095/connection-to-a-microsoft-sql-database-via-vba-adodb-with-the-lowest-risk-to-h/30299444#30299444 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744688/vba-macro-save-sql-query-in-a-csv-file/38747334#38747334 One solution is for integrated security `SSPI` as you have it and the other one allows for connections with username and password. Also, the code is very detailed and captures the different errors: (1) error reaching server (2) error connecting to server (3) error connecting to DB on server.

Comment: Use SQL Configuration manager and look at SQL Server Network Configuration, Protocols for SQLEXPRESS. Is TCP/IP or Named Pipes enabled? I have found several instances where SQL Express had these protocols disabled.