# Excel VBA : Error 3704 When executing SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have the following code to execute a sql statement and get records from server and paste it in a range :

```
Option Explicit
Const conString As String = "Provider = sqloledb;Server=dbsrv;Database=xxxx;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"
Public Function execSql(ByVal sql As String, ByVal pasteRange As Range) As Integer
On Error GoTo line

Dim rs  As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open conString

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open sql, cn

pasteRange.CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close

execSql = 0
Exit Function
line:
execSql = 1
End Function
```

This is the SQL statement that i am trying to execute :

```
DECLARE @startDate date,@endDate date
SET @startDate = [sgdb].[GNR].sgfn_ShamsiDateToDate(1397,1,1)
SET @endDate = [sgdb].[GNR].sgfn_ShamsiDateToDate(1397,1,5)

DECLARE @tblSold as TABLE (hdrID bigint,vchNo int,vchDate date,cstmrRef int, sold money)
INSERT INTO @tblSold
SELECT H.VchHdrId,H.VchNo,H.VchDate,H.CstmrRef,SUM(I.Price) AS Sold FROM [sgdb].[SLE].[SLEFactHdr] AS H JOIN [sgdb].[SLE].[SLEFactItm] AS I
ON I.VchHdrRef = H.VchHdrId
WHERE H.VchDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND H.[Status] = 1
GROUP BY H.VchHdrId,H.VchNo,H.VchDate,H.CstmrRef

DECLARE @tblRet as TABLE (hdrID bigint,vchNo int,vchDate date,cstmrRef int, ret money)
INSERT INTO @tblRet
SELECT  H.VchHdrId,H.VchNo,H.VchDate,H.CstmrRef,SUM(I.Price) AS Ret FROM [sgdb].[SLE].[SLERetFactHdr] H JOIN [sgdb].[SLE].[SLERetFactItm] I ON I.VchHdrRef = H.VchHdrId
WHERE H.VchDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate AND H.[Status] = 1
GROUP BY H.VchHdrId,H.VchNo,H.VchDate,H.CstmrRef

DECLARE @tblTax as TABLE (hdrID bigint, taxPrice money,taxType int,sr bit)
INSERT INTO @tblTax
SELECT I.VchHdrRef,SUM(TaxPrice),T.TaxType,0 FROM [sgdb].[SLE].[SLEFactItm] I JOIN [sgdb].[SLE].[SLEFactTax] FT ON FT.VchItmRef = I.VchItmId JOIN
[sgdb].[SLE].[SLETaxes] T ON T.TaxID = FT.TaxRef JOIN @tblSold TS ON TS.hdrID = I.VchHdrRef
GROUP BY I.VchHdrRef,T.TaxType

INSERT INTO @tblTax
SELECT I.VchHdrRef,SUM(TaxPrice),T.TaxType,1 FROM [sgdb].[SLE].[SLERetFactItm] I JOIN [sgdb].[SLE].[SLEFactTax] FT ON FT.VchItmRef = I.VchItmId JOIN
[sgdb].[SLE].[SLETaxes] T ON T.TaxID = FT.TaxRef JOIN @tblSold TS ON TS.hdrID = I.VchHdrRef
GROUP BY I.VchHdrRef,T.TaxType

DECLARE @tblFinalT as Table (cstmrRef int, cstmrName nvarchar(250), sold money,ret money,s_add money,s_dis money,r_add money,r_dis money)
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',sold,0,0,0,0,0 FROM @tblSold
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',0,ret,0,0,0,0 FROM @tblRet
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',0,0,T.taxPrice,0,0,0 FROM @tblTax T JOIN @tblSold S ON S.hdrID = T.hdrID WHERE T.sr = 0 AND T.taxType = 0
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',0,0,0,T.taxPrice,0,0 FROM @tblTax T JOIN @tblSold S ON S.hdrID = T.hdrID WHERE T.sr = 0 AND T.taxType = 1
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',0,0,0,0,T.taxPrice,0 FROM @tblTax T JOIN @tblRet R ON R.hdrID = T.hdrID WHERE T.sr = 1 AND T.taxType = 0
INSERT INTO @tblFinalT
SELECT cstmrRef,'',0,0,0,0,0,T.taxPrice FROM @tblTax T JOIN @tblRet R ON R.hdrID = T.hdrID WHERE T.sr = 1 AND T.taxType = 1

UPDATE @tblFinalT SET cstmrName = C.CstmrName FROM [sgdb].[SLE].[vwSLECstmrCrspnd] C WHERE cstmrRef = C.CstmrCode

DECLARE @tblFinal as Table (cstmrRef int, cstmrName nvarchar(250), sold money,ret money,s_add money,s_dis money,r_add money,r_dis money, total money)

INSERT INTO @tblFinal
SELECT T.cstmrRef,T.cstmrName,SUM(T.sold),SUM(T.ret),SUM(T.s_add),SUM(T.s_dis),SUM(T.r_add),SUM(T.r_dis),0 FROM @tblFinalT T
GROUP BY T.cstmrRef,T.cstmrName

UPDATE @tblFinal SET total = sold - ret + s_add - s_dis - r_add + r_dis

SELECT * FROM @tblFinal
```

When I try to execute the above statement, I get error

> '3704' : Application-defined or object-defined error.

Usually when this happens there must be something wrong with statement but i ran SQL Server Profiler and looks like the code is good. i Ran the same code in SQL Server itself and there is no problem. In fact Server actually sends data back but Excel VBA is getting the error.

I have experimented a lot of codes and turns out when i try to declare a temporary table inside my sql statement, this error pop up. If i turn this statement into a Stored Procedure, then code does just fine but i don't want to create a SP.

Is this a bad string connection ? or simply excel cannot handle this ? How can i solve this ?

Comment: @aaa `cn` is already defined.there is no need to use dim. it is the same. (i tried your suggestion btw) tried `Option Explicit` as you suggested. still getting same error

Comment: You'll need a `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of that SQL for ADO to recognise that there are records returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your SQL query with

`set nocount on;`

before the first line of SQL code and it will work.

Comment: If you experience any further problems with your connection you can use some of the trouble-shooting as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744688/vba-macro-save-sql-query-in-a-csv-file/38747334#38747334